# What password based key derivation does PKCS #12 use?

Tags: encryption, passwords, pbkdf2, pkcs12, pkcs8

I would like to make a note that I have read all of rfc 7292.

I am trying to decrypt encrypted private key in a pkcs#12 pfx file.

The private key is enveloped within pkcs#8 shrouded key bag.

The OID preceding encrypted private key represented as an octet string is

```
pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {pkcs-12PbeIds 3}
```

which I would take to assume that the private key is encrypted with Triple DES

CBC, and password derivation method is pbe.

RFC 7292 describes a "General Method" in section B.2 and B.3, and appendix C

clearly notes

```
here, we specify a few more, all of which use the procedure detailed in Appendices B.2 and B.3 to construct keys (and IVs, where needed).
```

Instructions in the first paragraph of Appendix B states, however,

```
 Specifically, PBES2 should be used as encryption scheme, with PBKDF2
   as the key derivation function.
```

So in this pfx file, is the private key is encrypted with a symmetric key derived from the general method described or is it more likely that it is encrypted by a symmetric derived by pbkdf2 ?

Also, PKCS#5 does not describe how IV is derived from PBKDF2. Where can I find
specification?

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph of RFC7272 appendix B, which is the *second* paragraph in original [RSA PKCS#12v1.1]
(http://www.emclink.net/collateral/white-papers/h11301-pkcs-12v1-1-personal-information-exchange-syntax-wp.pdf), 
*recommends* that PBES2/PBKDF2 from PKCS#5v2+ be used, but this is only 'should' 
(not even RFC2119 upper-case SHOULD) and the **scheme of appendices B and C** (all in B in original) 
*can* be used, and **is used** by the specific OID you quote.

Note RFC7292 as published has two typos in B.2 step 6 A, (only) one of which was previously errata-ed. 
I have reported this to the rfc-editor and they will fix the erratum;
until then you should use the original v1.1 (or v1). 
Or alternatively the code in a 
working and available implementation like OpenSSL (or its forks) or NSS or Java.

RFC7292 C (or PKCS#12v1+ B.4) says

> The PBES1 encryption scheme defined in PKCS #5 provides a number of
>      algorithm identifiers for deriving keys and IVs; here, we specify a
>      few more, all of which use the procedure detailed in Appendices B.2
>      and B.3 to construct keys (and IVs, where needed).

As stated, these schemes derive both the key and the IV if needed (which it is for 3TDES-CBC),
using different 'diversifier' inputs as described in B.3 and referenced in B.2.

In contrast PKCS#5 PBES1 derives both the key and IV from a single PBKDF1 operation, 
while PBES2 uses PBKDF2 to derive *only* the key; the IV if any is chosen separately, 
and carried in the parameters field of the AlgorithmIdentifier for PBES2.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer really clarifies it. I have one more question though, does EVP_BytesToKey() in openssl use the scheme in rfc#12? I set EVP_CIPHER as des_ede3_cbc and EVP_MD as sha1. 
Openssl man pages suggest it uses the scheme in PKCS#5 v1.5

Comment: @user45979 (I assume you mean PKCS#12; RFC#12 was way back during ARPAnet.) `EVP_BytesToKey` implements *an extension of* the scheme of PKCS#5 through v1.5, which is retronymed PBES1 and PBKDF1 in PKCS#5v2+ (and deprecated); for the hash and cipher combinations defined by PBES1 (which does not include TDES) `EVP_BytesToKey` is identical to PBKDF1. Which, for clarity, is similar to but *not the same as* PKCS#12 appendix B (and C for the RFC).